# How can I bring a specific network interface(s) down on boot, but keep them configured?

Tags: linux, debian, startup, network-interface

This is on a Debian/Raspbian based OS.
My goal is to have one or more network interfaces fully configured, but down.

I need to be able to just use `ifconfig wlan0 up` or `ifconfig eth0 up` to start them up.

What can I do to achieve this?  (This is a systemd based distro)

Comment: I haven't done it on Ubuntu/Debian in a long time. On Enterprise Linux it's fairly easy: add `ONBOOT=no` to the /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 script. I forget if that works for Debian, so I'm not posting as an official answer.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already have the interfaces configured as normal, each of the interfaces (e.g. eth0) should have an `auto eth0` or `allow-hotplug eth0` line in the config. Removing that line will prevent the interface from being started at boot.

`ifup eth0` or `ifconfig eth0 up` should then bring up the interface as configured.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following: [disable a network interface on booting ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/585852/disable-a-network-interface-on-booting-ubuntu)

You can add the interfaces that should not come up on boot on a new file 
`/etc/network/interfaces.noboot`, then bring them up when needed with:

```
sudo ifup -i /etc/network/interfaces.noboot -v eth1
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it to specifically be brought up with `ifconfig <interface> up`.  I need it to be fully configured already, but down, not left in an unconfigured state.